# Cannot find module crypto from web3.js

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, web3js

I already made a website using PHP.

On my website, I include the web3.js using  tag to use its function.
It was working and okay so far.

But when I tried it on IE 11, it is failing with error:
" Cannot find module crypto "
This is happened when it is executing web3.eth.accounts.create()

I wonder why this only happens in IE 11?
What is the solution or alternative way to solve?

I search for some references. But many of them are not caused by web3.js.
Other than that, they are using node.js or npm.
Mine is just plain PHP for now.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which kind of web3.js version are you using? From [this article](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/), when using web3.js, it requires the Node.js, please check the node.js version. Then, refer to [this thread](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1555).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I'm using web3.js version 1. Beta 34.
Hmm, it is weird then, I'm able to used it's function even without using node.js from php page. I used CDN to include it. But node.js is globally installed on my server, maybe that is why it is working. Not know for sure.

Anyway, my problem only occured in IE 11. Other than that, I can used web3.js in all other browser.

Comment: After checking the [web3.js document](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=crypto), the web3.eth.accounts got NOT audited until now and the web3.js 1.0 stable version isn’t released. I think perhaps this issue can be possible a web3.js 1.0 bug. I suggest you could post this issue at [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues). Also, you could try to use the version v0.x.x of web3.js.